# Pandas Drop levels and attach to column title

Tags: pandas

Using pivot function I have managed to obtain flatten data frame:

```
q_id                                     1              2      
a_id                                  1  2  3  4    5  6  7  8
movie_id     user_id    start_rating                           
931       284                 2.0     0  0  0  1    0  0  0  0   
804       648                 4.5     0  0  0  0    1  0  0  0   
840       414                 4.5     0  1  0  0    0  0  0  0   
843       419                 3.5     1  0  0  0    0  1  0  0   
848       132                 3.5     1  0  0  1    0  0  0  0
```

My goal was to remove the indexes and attached level to the column name.

```
movie_id     user_id    start_rating  1_1  1_2  1_3  1_4  2_5  2_6  2_7  2_8                         
931       284                 2.0     0  0  0  1    0  0  0  0   
804       648                 4.5     0  0  0  0    1  0  0  0   
840       414                 4.5     0  1  0  0    0  0  0  0   
843       419                 3.5     1  0  0  0    0  1  0  0   
848       132                 3.5     1  0  0  1    0  0  0  0
```

I tried following steps:

`df.columns = ['_'.join(col).strip() for col in df.columns.values]`

but getting:

```
    df.columns = ['_'.join(col).strip() for col in df.columns.values]
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join) works with strings, and the element of col are `int` as the error shows. You need to convert the element of `col` to `str`.

```
df.columns = ['_'.join([str(lev) for lev in col]).strip() for col in df.columns.values]
```

or because here you have two levels, do:

```
df.columns = ['{}_{}'.format(l1,l2) for l1, l2 in df.columns.values]
```